# template template parameter or template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, specialization

assume we have a class `DefaultClass` which is a template class. We have many classes 
that specialize traits `spec_traits`, lets call them `SpecClass1` itp. . `SpecClass#` itself can be
a template with one parameter, like so `SpecClass2<T>`. Is there an elegent way to implement`DefaultClass` so `DefaultClass<SpecClass1>` and  `DefaultClass<SpecClass<SomeType>, SomeType>` could be used. I use specialization:

```
// DefaultClass.hpp
template<typename T>
class _phonyTemplate;
class _phonyType;
class _phonyNonTemplate;

template <template <class> class TemplateT, class TypeT, class NonTemplateT>
class DefaultClass;

// for DefaultClass<SpecClass<SomeType>, SomeType>
template <template <class> class TemplateT, class TypeT>
class DefaultClass<TemplateT, TypeT, _phonyNonTemplate>
{
     // use SpecClass# traits
     typedef spec_traits<TemplateT<TypeT> >::some_type used_type;
};


// for DefaultClass<SpecClass1>
template <class NonTemplateT>
class DefaultClass<_phonyTemplate, _phonyType, NonTemplateT>
{
     // use SpecClass# traits
     typedef spec_traits<NonTemplateT>::some_type used_type;
};




// SpecClass1.hpp
class SpecClass1 : public DefaultType<_phonyTemplate, 
                                            _phonyType, SpecClass1> {};

// SpecClass2.hpp
template <typename TypeT>
class SpecClass2 : public DefaultType<SpecClass2, 
                                            TypeT, _phonyNonTemplateT> {};
```

Is there a better way then using those `_phony` types?

Comment: Nitpicks: There is no "template class", it is a "class template". And a class doesn't specialize a class template. A class template is specialized for a certain combination of template parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way seems to be for the spec types to provide a typedef for `SomeType`:

```
template <typename T>
class DefaultClass
{
    typedef typename T::SomeType SomeType;
};

// SpecClass1.hpp
class SpecClass1 : public DefaultType<SpecClass1> {};

// SpecClass2.hpp
template <typename TypeT>
class SpecClass2 : public DefaultType<SpecClass2<TypeT> > {};
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried this but thought it was worng due to other errors.